# ANSI C quoting: Why column -s $'\t' but column -s '\xHH' without using the $'...'?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I use the column command to reformat output, I know, I need to pass `$'...'` format to its -s (separator) option, if the separator is an [ANSI C backslash escape char](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html).

Example:

file1 and file2:

```
$ head *.txt
==> 1.txt <==
a
aa aaa aaa aaa
aaa

==> 2.txt <==
bbb
bbb
bbb
```

Reformating by `'\t'` (paste uses tab as default):

```
$ paste 1.txt 2.txt | column -s $'\t' -t
a               bbb
aa aaa aaa aaa  bbb
aaa             bbb
```

So far so good. **The `'\t'` must be in format `$'\t'`**

Now, I decide to use a different separator on the paste side, say `\x99`, an invisible char.

What I found is, on the *column* side I must pass `'\x99'` instead of `$'\x99'` to get the desired output. Why is that?

test1:

```
$ paste -d '\x99' 1.txt 2.txt | column -s $'\x99' -t
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

test2:

```
$ paste -d $'\x99' 1.txt 2.txt | column -s $'\x99' -t
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

test3:

```
$ paste -d '\x99' 1.txt 2.txt | column -s '\x99' -t
a               bbb
aa aaa aaa aaa  bbb
aaa             bbb
```

test4

```
$ paste -d $'\x99' 1.txt 2.txt | column -s '\x99' -t
a                     bbb
aa aaa aaa aaa        bbb
aaa                   bbb
```

**Anybody can explain the result of the tests above?** Thank you.

#### Environment:

- Bash : v 5.1.8
- column from util-linux 2.37

Comment: `#1  0x00007ffff7e395b3 in wcspbrk ()` My guess is that seg fault is at [here](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/text-utils/column.c#L180).

Comment: `for i in a b c d e; do echo $i > $i; done; paste -d '\x99' a b c d e | od -c`

Comment: This seems more like an issue with the `column` command, nothing related to the shell parsing.

Comment: "Segmentation fault" is always a bug in the program and never a problem with your invocation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Anybody can explain the result of the tests above?

#### `test1` and `test2`

Column tries to use locale (i.e. UTF-8) to parse input, `0x99` by itself (not preceded by `0xc2`) is an invalid Unicode sequence.

There is a bug in `column` that does not check if the string passed to `-s` is a valid Unicode string. `column` calls [`wcspbrk`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/text-utils/column.c#L180) to find `input_separator` (i.e. `$'\x99'`) in the input stream. Because the string `0x99` is an invalid UTF-8 sequence, `column` calls `wcspbrk` with `NULL` as second argument, and it causes seg fault.

```
+ gdb --args column -s $'\231' -t
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7e4a192 in __wcschr_sse2 () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#0  0x00007ffff7e4a192 in __wcschr_sse2 () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7e395b3 in wcspbrk () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00005555555588f6 in ?? ()
#3  0x00005555555575ba in ?? ()
#4  0x00007ffff7db7b25 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x000055555555826e in ?? ()
```

There is a missing check in `column` when [input arguments are parsed](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/text-utils/column.c#L816), it does not check if the return value of `mbs_to_wcs`, which calls `mbstowcs` to check the string passed to `-s`, is `NULL`. That could be fixed with something along:

```
    case 's':
        free(ctl.input_separator);
        ctl.input_separator = mbs_to_wcs(optarg);
        // --- snip --- MISSING FIX:
        if (ctl.input_separator == NULL) {
             errx(EXIT_FAILURE, _("blabla some message"));
        }
        // --- snip ---
        ctl.greedy = 0;
```

#### `test3`

The `-d` option to `paste` and `-s` option to `column`
specify *set of separators*. The `paste -d "\x99"` inserts just `x`, and because `-s "\x99"` `x` is in set of separators, it just separates on `x` character.

#### `test4`

It also seems that columns [converts broken sequences like `$'\x99'` into `\x99` form](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/text-utils/column.c#L555) just like that when reading from input. Because of that, when `paste` inserts the `0x99` byte, you can set `-s \x99`, because `column` will transform the byte in input into 4 bytes `\` `x` `9` `9` and after that work on the input to columnize it.

Then `-s \x99` detects 4 separators `\` `x` `9` `9` in sequence, so you get many spaces.

Anyway, the solution in any case is to use bytes lower than 128.

---

I submitted an issue to `util-linux` on github https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/issues/1425 and the issue will be most probably fixed, and it seems that next `column` version will error with an error message when an invalid UTF-8 sequence is given to `-s` command.

Comment: very well explained! Thank you! I often use `\x99` as a temp placeHolder in sed/awk.. to avoid the collision with the character in the content. It seems that it is not a wise choice. Probably, I can consider some chars like `\f` `\v`...

Comment: I use `0x01`, or if not `0x01`, then `0x02` or `0x03` typically. "Start of Header" and "Start/End of Text" ASCII characters always seemed like a good choice for a separator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed in util-linux upstream repository (https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/9714331843ef3a6d9c10ff1d3bc5fcf53d44d930) and the change will be available in the next release.